# Error while populating a dependent dropdown list in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, vbe

I used this code:

```
 <code><span>Sub PopulateddState()</span>
    <code><span> Select Case ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddRegion").Result</span>
    <code><span> Case "North"</span>
    <code><span> With ActiveDocument.FormFields     ("ddState").DropDown.ListEntries</span>
    <code><span> .Clear</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Michigan"</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Ohio"</span>
    <code><span> End With</span>
    <code><span> Case "South"</span>
    <code><span> With ActiveDocument.FormFields   ("ddState").DropDown.ListEntries</span>
    <code><span> .Clear</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Georgia"</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Texas"</span>
    <code><span> End With</span>
    <code><span> Case "East"</span>
    <code><span> With ActiveDocument.FormFields  ("ddState").DropDown.ListEntries</span>
    <code><span> .Clear</span>
    <code><span> .Add "New York"</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Maine"</span>
    <code><span> End With</span>
    <code><span> Case "West"</span>
    <code><span> With ActiveDocument.FormFields("ddState").DropDown.ListEntries</span>
    <code><span> .Clear</span>
    <code><span> .Add "California"</span>
    <code><span> .Add "Oregon"</span>
    <code><span> End With</span>
    <code><span> End Select</span>
    <code><span> End Sub</span>`
```

From this website: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-to-populate-a-dependent-dropdown-list-in-word/

Everytime I try and enter it into VBE it says:

> expected line number or statement or end of statement

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please get rid of all the html - `<code>`, `<span>` and `</span>`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me, though I'd be inclined to use:

```
Sub PopulateStates()
Dim FmFldList As ListEntries
With ActiveDocument
  Set FmFldList = .FormFields("ddState").DropDown.ListEntries
  Select Case .FormFields("ddRegion").Result
    Case "North"
      With FmFldList
        .Clear
        .Add "Michigan"
        .Add "Ohio"
      End With
    Case "South"
      With FmFldList
        .Clear
        .Add "Georgia"
        .Add "Texas"
      End With
    Case "East"
      With FmFldList
        .Clear
        .Add "New York"
        .Add "Maine"
      End With
    Case "West"
      With FmFldList
        .Clear
        .Add "California"
        .Add "Oregon"
      End With
  End Select
End With
End Sub
```

PS: When posting code please select the code use the {} symbol on the toolbar, not your own tagging.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was finally able to get it to work!